# global name not getting define - python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to run this:

```
import unittest
import wd.parallel
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
import copy
class Selenium2OnSauce(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_capabilities = []

        browser = copy.copy(webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
        browser['version'] = '10'
        browser['platform'] = 'XP'
        browser['name'] = 'Python at Sauce'
        browser['tags'] = "Parallel"
        desired_capabilities += [browser]

        self.drivers = wd.parallel.Remote(
            desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities,
            command_executor="http://user-string:key-string@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"
        )

    def ajax_complete(driver):
        try:
            return 0 == driver.execute_script("return JQuery.active")
        except WebDriverException:
            pass    

    @wd.parallel.multiply
    def test_sauce(self):
        self.driver.get('http://url.com')
        username = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_username')
        print "Found Username"
        username.send_keys('i1@example.com')
        print "Username Entered"

        password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_password')
        print "Found Password"
        password.send_keys('testuser')        
        print "Password Entered"

        password.submit()
        print "Logged in"

        self.driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Notification')[0].click()
        print "Going to Notification"

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            ajax_complete, "Timeout waiting for page to load"
        )

        print "ajax loaded string" in self.drive.page_source

    @wd.parallel.multiply
    def tearDown(self):
        print("Link to your job: https://saucelabs.com/jobs/%s" % self.driver.session_id)
        self.driver.quit()
        print "Quit"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I do so I get this:

```
Found Username
Entered Username
Found Password
Entered Password
Logged in
Going to Cal
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/wd/parallel.py", line 88, in thread_func
    f(SubTest(driver))
  File "functionalTest.py", line 57, in test_sauce
    ajax_complete, "Timeout waiting for page to load"
NameError: global name 'ajax_complete' is not defined
Link to your job: https://saucelabs.com/jobs/06022dc1f54548d98a75f59bd211848d
Quit
```

I think I'm having trouble accessing the var call `ajax_complete`, but i don't know why!

At the end of the day what I want to do is wait for all ajax to be completed before I run my next test...

NOTE: I'm a python newbie, So I'm sorry is this question is really silly.

Answer (score 1):

Methods in Python are accessed via `self`:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
    self.ajax_complete, "Timeout waiting for page to load"
)
```

Note that the `ajax_complete` method itself also needs to take `self` as the first argument.

Comment: Alternatively, `ajax_complete` could be defined as a function outside the class or as a static method.

Comment: like this: `def ajax_complete(self):
  try:
   return 0 == self.driver.execute_script("return JQuery.active")
  except WebDriverException:
   pass`